# Do all types of phones have a C:\ drive?

Tags: java-me

I don't know whether all mobiles have a c:\ drive as a memory location or not.  Kindly let me know if you know the answer.

Comment: The phrase "memory location" sounds like you're talking about RAM.  `C:` usually refers to the root of the primary filesystem on Windows, which exists on a disk, not RAM.  Most phones aren't based on Windows (but many are), so most phones don't have a `C:\` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android is based on some Unix, so it doesn't have it. It has the usual Unix directories like /bin, /etc.

Answer (score 2):

Some do and some don't; the only way to be sure for Java-ME is to use `FileSystemRegistry.listRoots()`.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the mobile have C drive and some of them had E drive.For example "Nokia c2" mobile have c drive and "Sony ericsson z530i" mobile had E drive.So the drive for memory is the vendor dependent.

Comment: Some of the nokia phones have E and C drives.